# take a screenshot in android then use it in another activity

Tags: android, bitmap, screenshot

So I have seen alot of questions and answers on how to take a screenshot and save it to external storage, but what I would like to know is how after I have done this I can read it into the next activity,
I will also be using the image when I open the app another time so I don't think a bundle will be enough.
I know it seems simple and probably is so thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use intent bundle to pass the screenshot's file path between Activities, and you can use SharedPreferences to persistent the path for next time loading.

Save bitmap to external storage:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
fos.flush();
fos.close();
String path = file.getPath();
```

Pass path between Activities:

```
intent.putExtra(PATH, path);
```

Persistence:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
sp.edit().putString(PATH, path).commit(); //save
sp.getString(PATH, null); //read
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the location of the file you saved the screenshot at and pass it as a String in the Intent when creating the new Activity.

Then you reopen the image file in you new activity.